# What commands are included in the command 'adduser'?

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have read this source below and it states that adduser is a script which is essentially a collection of commands such as: 'useradd', 'passwd', 'groupadd', etc.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121071/what-does-adduser-do-that-useradd-doesnt

"Further investigation of adduser reveals that it is a perl script providing a high level interface to, and thus offering some of the functionality of, the following commands:

useradd

groupadd

passwd - used to add/change users passwords.

gpasswd - used to add/change group passwords.

usermod - used to change various user associated parameters.

chfn - used to add/change additional information held on a user.

chage - used to change password expiry information.

edquota - used to change disk usage quotas."

But from what i understand, 'edquota' is not a command. Furthermore when i execute 'adduser' files from '/etc/skel' are copied so isn't the `cp` utilised?
Furthermore which command prompts the user to re-enter their password?

So my question: Can someone explain where each command is executed and what it does? [when executing the 'adduser' command]

Comment: because adduser is a perl script...

Comment: You do realize that those commands it runs can do things too right? Like copy `/etc/skel` files perhaps? And `edquota` is absolutely a command. A simple google search for it will find it for example.

Answer (score 1):

`adduser` can be considered as an aggregate of all the mentioned commands, well to some extent at least !!

The best way to find all the internals is to read the source yourself.

Open the `perl` source file with your favorite editor, for example to open in `vim`:

```
vim "$(command -v adduser)"
```

and start discovering.

Check `man adduser` and all other command's man pages too.

Also you don't have the `edqota` command (used to edit filesystem quota for users) because it comes with the `quota` package and presumably you don't have it installed.

Comment: @pythontamer Whats the link for?

Comment: It's the output of vim "$(command -v adduser)". I don't understand what it's meant to show me.

Comment: @pythontamer Whats teh output of `echo "$(command -v adduser)"`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Why is that?

Comment: Because `command -v adduser` and `echo "$(command -v adduser)"` will output *exactly* the same thing only the former is one less subshell, etc.

Comment: @EtanReisner duh..its muscle memory probably ;)

Comment: @pythontamer: Try `cat "$(command -v adduser)"` or `cat /usr/sbin/adduser`